# Ferromagnetic Potts models in a field and the endpoint of their first-order lines

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, critical-phenomena

The $q=3$, $d=3$ ferromagnetic [Potts model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potts_model#Standard_Potts_model) has a first-order transition on varying temperature. I recently learned that at small $h>0$, where $h$ is a field favoring one of the three colors, there is *still* a first-order transition on varying temperature. I hadn't appreciated until now that first-order transitions could be resilient against explicitly symmetry-breaking terms.

At large enough $h>0$, the first-order transition disappears. The end-point of the first-order transition line is described by the $d=3$ Ising universality class, and this has been numerically seen in e.g. [this paper.](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/0007019)

I am trying to learn what happens in other models with first-order transitions. For specificity, I'll restrict to the Potts model in $d=2$ and $d=3$ with an external field. The transition is first order at zero field for $d=2$ and $q \geq 5$, and is first-order at zero field for $d=3$ and $q \geq 3$. What happens at the critical points at the end of their first-order lines at nonzero $T$ and $h$? Specifically, what are their universality classes?